# Run ASP.NET MVC site in subdirectory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

My project currently runs on this url http://locahost:55001. But I want it to run in http://localhost:55001/test. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this prodecure:

- Open MVC project in VS
- On "Explore Solution" open "Properties"
- Select "Debug" tab
- Near "Server Web Settings" change the "App's URL" from **http://localhost:55001** to **http://localhost:55001/test**
- Save and run application.

Hope have been helpful.